# dummy variables, interaction with continuous variable, and variable selection

Tags: categorical-data, interaction, stepwise-regression

I want to predict shop sales from a set of independent variables which consists of shop attributes like floor space, no. of stuff of a specific store (continuous variables) and also location of the store which is a categorical variable (binary coding) like east west south. I have some questions.

1. If I run stepwise regression for variable selection and if one of the included dummy variable gets dropped , what does that mean?
2. Is it necessary to include interaction terms with dummy variables and continuous variables if they are significant? I am asking this because my motive is to predict sales.
3. Should I include interaction terms before running stepwise regression?

Comment: Stepwise regression is generally not a preferred technique.

Answer (score 1):

1. If by dummy variables you're referring to multiple binary variables that make up one categorical predictor, each of them needs to be in the model for each other dummy to be meaningful. In stepwise regression either they are all in or all out, but not piecemeal. Are you doing this by hand or something? All stats packages I'm familiar with treat multilevel categoricals properly in this respect, and shouldn't consider dummy variables independently for model specification.
2. Again, you can't include interactions with some dummy variables of a single categorical predictor but not others. All in or all out. The test of whether the interaction needs to be included is a comparison between a model without interactions with all dummies and a model with interactions with all dummies. If the interaction is significant, you should keep it in any case. Just be aware that the interpretation of the "main effects" changes drastically when interactions are included in models.
3. If doing backwards stepwise regression, include the interaction terms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Sir, I am relatively new to regression. Sir can you just explain me how will you interprete main effects in the model considering interaction terms are significant. Assuming you have 2 independent variables one continous like floor space and another categorical like "type of the outlet" having 3 levels Hypermarket, Supermarket , Grocery. Dependent variable is Shop turnover which is metric. So my question is how will I interpete the main effect assuming interaction effect to be significant? Will it be any specific  interpretation or normal interpretation for main effects ?

Comment: Also are you suggesting I can use backward selection for a model with categorical and many continuous variables, also interactions, and the model will automatically treat categorical variables in a different manner: suppose I use PROC GLM for instance

Comment: As soon as interactions are in the model, the interpretation of the "main effects" changes. For simplicity, let's assume you have two independents, one continuous, and the other categorical having only two levels (it gets more complicated with 3 or more), and we can use the ones you list above (say the levels are Hypermarket and Supermarket). Once the interaction is in the model, the interpretation of main effect is the "slope" when the other term is equal to 0.

Comment: So if your model is turnover = space + outlet + space*outlet, the parameter estimate for outlet refers to the difference between outlet types when space = 0. the parameter estimate for space refers to the change in turnover per unit change in space when outlet = 0. Behind the scenes, PROC GLM codes binary variables for categoricals, and will code alphabetically, so Hypermarket will be 0, and Supermarket will be 1. Therefore, the estimate for space will be the effect of space for Hypermarkets, ignoring Supermarkets.

Comment: If you have more than 2 levels, PROC GLM wil create more than two variables. Look up "dummy coding". The principle is the same. The effect of space for the model specified as above will be when BOTH variables = 0, which again will be coded alphabetically, so if you have all three of your outlets, the effect of space will the slope when outlet = Grocery.

Comment: Im not an expert with SAS, so I don't know how its stepwise functions work, but SAS should treat continuous variables, 2-level categoricals, many-level categoricals, and interactions in the same way. Put them all in (turn = space + outlet + space*outlet), then run the stepwise removal. It will remove the highest order terms, test whether the model is better or worse without them, then either keep them out or put them back in, then move on to other terms.

Comment: read Data Analysis: A Model Comparison Approach. Excellent and very accessible textbook on regression.

Comment: Got your point sir. Really appreciate your help. dummy variables doubts are solved . now if we have multicollinearity in our data and if we do have to group the variables (to reduce multicollinearity), with each group being uncorrelated with the other group which is the best process to do so-PCA method, Factor analysis or Cluster analysis?

Comment: what is the difference between these three method's ? and how will the categorical variables be treated in such situations?

Comment: not really sure about the differences. PCA is probably fine. just get ready for interpretation to become confusing. glad to help. good luck.

Comment: If you are using PROC GLM as you indicated, since you are new to regression, then you need to understand how dummy coding works in GLM.  You will need to make sure you set the "PARAM=" statement to obtain the coding you are working with if you want to have an accurate interpretation of your results (depending on what you are doing).